# Add object is not iterable

Tags: function, sympy

so i am getting this error when using sympy,

```
#base packages
import sympy as sp
from sympy import log, exp,symbols,IndexedBase,Symbol


x = IndexedBase('x', real=True)    
y = IndexedBase("y",real = True)
n, i = symbols('n, i', integer=True, positive=True) 
beta1 = Symbol('beta1', real=True) 
beta0 = Symbol('beta0', real=True)
objective = sum(y[i]*log(1/(1+exp(-beta0-beta1*x[i])))+(1-y[i])*log(1-(1/(1+exp(-beta0-beta1*x[i])))),(i, 0, n-1))
```

and the error being,

```
'Add' object is not iterable
```

any idea, where i could be going wrong?

Y

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Python builtin `sum` rather than sympy's symbolic `Sum`:

```
In [4]: sum(1, (i, 0, n-1))                                                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ae313784d13c> in <module>
----> 1 sum(1, (i, 0, n-1))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

In [5]: Sum(1, (i, 0, n-1))                                                                                                                    
Out[5]: 
n - 1  
 ___   
 ╲     
  ╲    
  ╱   1
 ╱     
 ‾‾‾   
i = 0
```

If I change it to `Sum` then I get:

```
In [6]: objective                                                                                                                              
Out[6]: 
n - 1                                                                        
 ____                                                                        
 ╲                                                                           
  ╲   ⎛              ⎛            1         ⎞      ⎛        1         ⎞     ⎞
   ╲  ⎜(1 - y[i])⋅log⎜1 - ──────────────────⎟ + log⎜──────────────────⎟⋅y[i]⎟
   ╱  ⎜              ⎜     -β₀ - β₁⋅x[i]    ⎟      ⎜ -β₀ - β₁⋅x[i]    ⎟     ⎟
  ╱   ⎝              ⎝    ℯ              + 1⎠      ⎝ℯ              + 1⎠     ⎠
 ╱                                                                           
 ‾‾‾‾                                                                        
i = 0
```